# Need help improving this Python function for determining Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD)

Tags: python, function

```
def what_is_mad(list_of_nums):
    xbar = what_is_mean(list_of_nums)
    for num in list_of_nums:
        value1 = list_of_nums[0]
        value2 = list_of_nums[1]
        value3 = list_of_nums[2]
        value4 = list_of_nums[3]
        test = abs(value1 - xbar) + abs(value2 - xbar) + abs(value3 - xbar) + abs(value4 - xbar)
        mad = test / xbar
    return int(mad)

what_is_mad(2, 2, 4, 4)
```

I'm trying to build my own purely Python function for determining Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) and would like some recommendations on how I can enhance this code. It is currently limited to four values, as seen above, but I'd like to be able to have the function ingest any number of values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't the for loop just calculate the same value every time?

Comment: Why bother with the loop and then hard code the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way(formula) of calculating the Mean absolute deviation is wrong in your code. You should calculate all your absolute deviations, sum them up and divide by the number of elements in the list_of_sums, not by the mean. If you mean pure python as not using any libraries this code will do.

```
xbar = sum(list_of_nums)/len(list_of_nums)
dev = 0
for num in list_of_nums:
    dev = dev + abs(num - xbar)
mad = dev/len(list_of_nums)
print(mad)
```

You can use list comprehension and write the code in less number of lines. But it would create another list which will cost space to store it, hence not optimized.

Otherwise you can use numpy, scipy or pandas and they have inbuilt functions to calculate MAD

Comment: Gayal, did you mean to write ```mad = dev / len(list_of_sums)``` as it doesn't appear that test is defined anywhere in this code block.

Comment: @Tweep try it now

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Gayal!

Comment: @GayalKuruppu you are incorrect about list comprehension. You should read up on generator expressions. There is no extra space requirement for generator expressions.

Comment: @jodag I did not say anything about generator expressions, just about list comprehensions(which you were using in your code at that time not generator expressions).

Answer (score 0):

```
xbar = mean(list_of_nums)
test=0
for num in list of nums:
    test = test + abs(num - xbar)
mad = test/xbar
return int(mad)
```

This loops through the list and sums up the absolute deviations one at a time, then does the mad calculation.

Comment: I received this error when I ran the suggested code. I think it has to do with a previous function for determining the mean which I'm using in the current function for determining MAD. If that makes sense. The error was a zero division error.

Comment: @Tweep, your error didn't go through, but you can certainly use your mean function. I was simply writing in shorthand

Comment: you get zero division error because your formula is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of an optimized solution, [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) has a method for this.

```
mad_in = [1,2,3,4...]

mad_out = pandas.Series(mad_in).mad()
```

Comment: OP said they were building a purely python function. Any idea is that pandas function is C accelerated?  I know some of pandas is.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess this probably would be out of their purely Python function idea either way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a couple lines using python's built-in `sum` operation and list comprehension

```
def what_is_mad(*list_of_nums):
    count = len(list_of_nums)
    mean = sum(list_of_nums) / count
    mad = sum((abs(num - mean) for num in list_of_nums)) / count
    return mad
```

Comment: Aren't you creating an extra list just to hold the abs deviation values? It's just wasting space. you can use a simple for loop and save that space.

Comment: @GayalKuruppu I edited to remove the list and now use a generator to avoid creating a list in memory. Though if OP were worried about efficiency I think they would be using a 3rd party library which would be more efficient than operating on python lists.

Comment: What is the * in front of list_of_nums?

Comment: It allows you to pass an arbitrary number of positional arguments to `what_is_mad` so that you can call it as you have specified in your question (i.e. `what_is_mad(2, 2, 4, 4)` rather than passing a list or tuple `what_is_mad((2, 2, 4, 4))`). See [this](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) for more information.

Comment: @jodag you are calling a LIST of numbers and expecting it to be *args. How will he pass the *args if he has let's see thousands of inputs? the easiest way is to give a list. Aren't you just overcomplicating things?

Comment: I'm answering the question that OP asked? The use case OP gave was `what_is_mad(2,2,4,4)`. Besides you can still invoke this function as `what_is_mad(*(2,2,4,4))`. I don't see how there's anything overly complex about the function I provided here.

Comment: use case of OP was what_is_mad([2,2,4,4]) not what_is_mad(2,2,4,4). besides if you are to do what_is_mad(*(2,2,4,4)), there is no need for the *args.

Comment: The last line of code to invoke the function in OP's post is `what_is_mad(2, 2, 4, 4)` which seems to indicate that's how they wanted to invoke the function no? There's nothing wrong with either way. You seem to have a problem with *args for some reason though I'm not quite sure why? In some cases it will reduce the number of keystrokes and in some cases it will increase the number of keystrokes so the decision should be made depending on the most common use case. But it's all still irrelevant since I wrote the answer based on the call style that was in the original question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯